# What would you want in an ideal debugger?

Tags: debugging

Just food for thought:

What features would you consider in an ideal debugging tool?

What about debugging tools for distributed systems?

What do you think is missing from current debugging tools?

Comment: More suitable question for programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Being able to step backwards would make me very happy C person.

Answer (score 0):

I would really like to see some more artificial intelligence in debuggers. Like they should be able to know which bug I was looking for and fix it automatically. Distributed AI would be even better. One day I dream of submitting a README to github and the code would be written for me automatically, 100% bug-free of course.

:-)